# Base class of everything in c++

Tags: c++, exception

In Java, the `Object` class is the base class of all classes. Is there any such class in C++ as well?

My motivation for the question is:

```
try
{
    if (something) throw int(a);
    if (something) throw char(b);
    if (something) throw float(c);
}
catch(...)
{
    handle
}
```

Is there any other way to handle all these exceptions using single catch block apart from this?

Comment: There's no mandatory / implicit base class in C++, unlike Java. And I'm not sure you can throw built-in primitive data types.

Comment: That just seems like bad design to me. What is the *actual* problem you want to solve?

Comment: of course you can throw them. If you want to handle all of them in a single catch block, you need to throw a uniform interface.

Comment: `int`, `char`, and `float` are not classes anyway, so it wouldn't help you here. There *is* a `std::exception` you can use as a base class for your exceptions, if you want to.

Comment: There is a base class use by the standard library for exceptions (std::exception)   It is suggested that you use or extend it for your own exceptions (if you need to own types - the standard library already has quite a few) See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no universal base class in C++.

Exception classes should usually derive from `std::exception`, so that `catch(const std::exception&)` can be used.

`catch(...)` catches any exception object type (including primitive types). It can be rethrown inside the `catch` block with `throw;`:

```
try
{
    if (something) throw int(a);
    if (something) throw char(b);
    if (something) throw float(c);
}
catch(...)
{
    if(stillFailed) throw; // throws the same exception again
}
```

It is also possible to get a `std::exception_ptr` object which represents the thrown object (of unknown type), using `std::current_exception()`, inside the `catch(...)` block. It can then be compared for equality with other `std::exception_ptr` objects, or rethrown from another function using `std::rethrow_exception()`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/exception . There is no way to get direct access to the exception object, because its type is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

The most universal type for such cases is `std::string` (after all, even the most complex programs are simply arrays of characters).

Encode your object into a text form and parse/interpret it on the handling side.

```
template<class T>
std::string toString(const T& x);

try
{
    if (something) throw toString(int(a));
    if (something) throw toString(char(b));
    if (something) throw toString(float(c));
}
catch(const std::string& ex)
{
    decode and handle
}
```

However, if you'd be willing to take this approach, then C++ is not the right language for doing your programming - better switch to a text-oriented or dynamic language.

Comment: Or write subclasses of `std::exception` that wrap your primitive types, and hopefully provide names that have a semantic explanation of why the primitives have been thrown, rather than us just having to guess what's going on when reading the `catch` block...

Answer (score 0):

No,there any other way to handle all these exceptions using single catch block apart.

different catch blocks are needed to handle different data types throw.
like 
for int 
catch(int m)

for char
(char m)

etc.